# Delphi, linking database stored on onedrive

Tags: database, delphi, onedrive, pascal

I would like to connect my ado connection to a database stored on onedrive so after the development of my application... It can be distributed to multiple users without them having a copy of the database. So when they submit information on the application it will automatically get added to the database that is stored on my onedrive. Please assist.

Comment: OneDrive gives each user a copy of a file before syncing an updated version of it back to the cloud if they made changes. This does not allow multiple users to access the same file at the same time which is required for file based databases like an Access .ACCDB .

Comment: I understand. What suggestion would you make or how would you go about doing this. And I will be using a .MDB file not .ACCDB.

Comment: You need to use a real online DB like e.g. MySQL or MariaDB, stored on a server accessible over the internet.

Comment: .MDB is still an example of file based databases like an Access .ACCDB